# How to draw lines with a certain amount of thickness

Tags: c++, rendering, direct3d, direct3d11

What is the best way to draw lines with a variable amount of thickness in the new Direct3D?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280077/direct3d-line-thickness http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476342%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#Full

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Please answer instead of reply so I can accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal What is your definition of an answer?

Comment: A statement/explanation/description of a solution to the stated problem. Read the SO FAQ.

Comment: I did. I didn't find anything saying that links are not allowed to be valid answers. (I could have overlooked it..) But if you don't want to answer, fine :P

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I slightly disagree, but I'm not going in detail because I think the discussion would take too much time and certainly not of life importance. I'll keep in mind though. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to join the discussion on that meta question if you disagree with the general concensus. I'm sure we'd be happy to hear your views.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to draw patterned/thick lines (and 2D vector shapes generally) with Direct3D 11 is to use Direct2D. With DirectX 11.1 (Windows 8.x or Windows 7 SP1 with KB [2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838)) it's trivial to use Direct2D on a Direct3D 11 device. Prior to that, you have to use Direct2D on a Direct3D 10.1 device and shared-surfaces with a Direct3D 11 device (see [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx) for some notes with the DirectX 11.1 on Windows 7 scenario.